# Computational complexity of backsolve in R

Tags: r

What is the computational complexity of [R backsolve function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/backsolve.html)? I don't see any info about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`backsolve`cites the LINPACK User's Guide: Dongarra, J. J., Bunch, J. R., Moler, C. B. and Stewart, G. W. (1978) LINPACK Users Guide. Philadelphia: SIAM Publications, that is currently found [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971811)

Looking in the R code reveals that the main work is done by the Fortran function `dtrsm`. Looking for "dtrsm" and "complexity" (or similar) finds some books and papers.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! But what is the complexity then? I mean, of this particular implementation.

Comment: As far as I see, R uses the standard algorithm. As far as I see it seems to be "cubic".

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it... the matrices are triangular, so I already see quadratic solution possible...

Comment: One can of course do simulations, but I think its best to buy the original LINPACK docs and/or to post the question to [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel).